# Synonym [DOM-Inspector] for [dominspector]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

May I recommend the synonym [dom-inspector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dom-inspector) for [dominspector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dominspector)?

Comment: This raises an interesting question: should there be a single tag representing all developer tools for all (major) browsers, or should each implementation of dev tools have its own tag for differentiating between feature sets?

Comment: @BoltClock IMO I think it should just be for all browsers. If clarification is needed for which browser they can either tag that browser in the question or mention it in the question itself.

Comment: @BoltClock Hmmm... interesting question.  I think questions pertaining to DOM Inspector are specific to that tool.  At the same time, a cross-browser dominspector tag is also useful.

Answer (score 3):

Putting aside [BoltClock's "interesting question"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350095/synonym-dom-inspector-for-dominspector#comment478510_350095) about whether there should be a single tag representing all developer tools for the moment...

This is a simple request, and it only affects 7 measly questions, so I've gone ahead and done it. Actually, I didn't see the point in a synonym. I just renamed the [dominspector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dominspector) tag to [dom-inspector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dom-inspector), since "DOM Inspector" (with a space) is the name of the plug-in.

The tag auto-completion should be sufficient to get people to choose [dom-inspection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dom-inspection) (if anyone is actually using this plug-in anymore...)